# Putty connection manager running

Tags: putty

This is the first time I'm trying to run putty connection manager. I have created a database and a SSH connection in it. When i try to run , I get

```
"Unable to find PuTTY sessions (registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions' does not exist)"
```

(P.S. when i run it for first time it doesn't asked me for the location of putty.exe. )

help me to proceed.
Thanks in advance

```
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:Unable to find PuTTY sessions (registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions' does not exist)
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:Unable to find PuTTY sessions (registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions' does not exist)
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:Unable to find PuTTY sessions (registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions' does not exist)
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:RUNTIME ERROR
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:  Main error : Unable to attach PuTTY process
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:  Internal error : Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:  StackTrace : 
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:     at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainWindowHandle()
at x48b98d898b67428b.x1521d5c1a2ad9cb1.x1248f643d518e66f(x6f302b004bee2deb x69e8923140f2b0a6, xb6e5bd3523128419 xd617aefdd9defbf0)
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:RUNTIME ERROR
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:  Main error : Unable to attach PuTTY process
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:  Internal error : Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:  StackTrace : 
12/22/2010 1:42:12 PM:     at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainWindowHandle()
at x48b98d898b67428b.x1521d5c1a2ad9cb1.x1248f643d518e66f(x6f302b004bee2deb x69e8923140f2b0a6, xb6e5bd3523128419 xd617aefdd9defbf0)
```

(I got another error when i run for next time)

Answer (score 2):

[Tools --> Options --> Plug-ins ---> Putty ---> Location]

The above PuttyCM configuration value was set wrongly to 
"C:\Users\user-id\Desktop\puttycm.exe". 
Updated that configuration correctly to "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe". 
Then, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used Putty before? If not, Putty sessions aren't stored in registry and therefore Putty connection manager won't work.

Short version: use Putty at least once, then use conn. manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem as this. Up until today it has been working fine.

The two solutions I've found online to the problem are:

- Run puttycm.exe as Administrator
- Reinstall putty and puttycm

The first works but is a hassle, the second I can't figure out since it seems stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when migrating my system from WinXP to Win7. To solve the problem I just installed putty.exe in the PuttyCM installation folder, run putty.exe once and after this the error message was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on puttycm exe and go to properties, then go to the compatibility tab and click on "Run this program as an administrator" check box and then open it and it will work without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to "Office 2007" theme (*Tools -> Options -> General -> Theme*)
2. Restart `puttycm`
3. Put in the location of putty (*Tools -> Options -> Plugins -> Putty*)
4. Then it runs...

Hope this helps any. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. For my case, the problem happens when the option "show tray icon" is desabled. I just enabled this and the error was fixed. 
Tools >> Options >> General >> [v] Show tray icon (restart necessary).

Good luck!